# Access word documents header containing a table with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I need to read the pure text values from cells of a table located in the page header of a word document using vbscript.

All i could achieve until now is to read some kind of text from the header by this:

```
wscript.echo WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.FormattedText.Text
```

But how can i gain access to the table object and read each cell value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in Word documents can be enumerated via the [`Tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257959%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection.

```
For Each tbl In WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Tables
  For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
      WScript.Echo tbl.Cell(i, j).Value
    Next
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Sure, but the table i must access in located in the page header. And this seems not to list this table.